# How Can i Close Child Form when Click on Parent Form?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am having some trouble in my Windows form application. I have 2 forms:

1st Main / Parent Form

2nd Sub / Child Form (Menu)

Problem:

I want to close my 2nd form (which opens on top of 1st form) when I click on the 1st form.

Comment: Elaborate ur question. post some code there..

Answer (score 1):

You can register to the main form "on focus" event (this link is a basic tutorial that shows how to register for events in VB: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets10p1.html)

when that event occurs you will have to check if the second form is open (save a reference to the opened form so you can do that) and then close it.

If you will add some code i will be able to be more specific...

Comment: My Forms are Models Form.  Parent form is deactivated when child form opens and until user click OK or cancel  button in child form (means we have to close child form to activate Parent form). and form activted not worked in that situation.

Comment: So you can just register to the child form "Lost focus" event - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx and just write "this.Close();" (in vb syntax thought).
you can even control how to close the form (DialogResult value) before you close it

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private childForm As Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        childForm = New Form2()
        childForm.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Activated
        If childForm IsNot Nothing Then
            childForm.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Parent form is deactivated when child form opens and until user click OK or cancel  button in child form (means we have to close child form to activate Parent form). and form activted not worked in that situation.

Comment: I''m confused.  I thought you said you wanted the child form to go away when you click on the parent, but now you're telling me you can't click on the parent at all.  I'm not following what your actual problem is.  I suspect you have multiple problems that you are blurring together and it's getting confusing.  I don't know what you mean by "Models form".  Do you mean a form that is the view for an MVC model?

Answer (score 0):

When u show your child-form u have to save the child-form in a variable in the parent-form. on a click on the parent-form you can use the variable to close or dispose your child-form